# $locationChangeStart only on back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a $locationChangeStart in my code, but I only want it to execute when the browser's back button is pressed. Is something like this even possible?

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$log', '$location', function($rootScope, $http, $log, $location) {

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {

        ... only run this on back button? ...

    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can "make it run" only if the browser's back button triggered the routechange but you CAN find out if the browser is trying to go back to the previous route.

That could be triggered by either hitting "back" in the browser or actually navigating to the previously visited url.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    var previousUrl;    

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {

        if (previousUrl && previousUrl === newUrl) {
            //Browser is navigating back
        } else {
            previousUrl = oldUrl;
        }

    }
}]);
```

But if this is part of some devious scheme to hijack the back-button, please dont. Most users will not approve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only on browsers that supports HTML5 History API

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html

You can then check state in you `$locationChangeStart` listener and do action only on history back behaviour